# Coordinates of the point cloud are shifted after voxelizing with PDAL

Tags: pdal

I used PDAL commands to voxelize the point cloud with folloiwing code. When I opened the results in Cloud Compare it didn't overlap with original point cloud. Is there any potential reason?

```
[
    "input.las",
    {
        "type":"filters.voxeldownsize",
        "cell":0.02,
        "mode":"center"
    },
    "output.las"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`filters.voxeldownsize` takes the points in a particular voxel of cell size `cell` and makes a point in the CENTER of the voxel. They are not going to overlap the original point cloud.

I think what you are hoping to have is [`filters.voxelcentroidnearestneighbor`](https://pdal.io/en/latest/stages/filters.voxelcentroidnearestneighbor.html)